# Is FLAGS_v defined implicitly in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve a multiple definitions error which seems to be happening because two libraries I'm using define the same thing twice. The libraries in question are pytorch and openfst.

But if I go into the openfst `src/` and do `grep -Ir 'FLAGS_v'` this is what I get:

```
extensions/linear/fstlinear.cc:   FLAGS_unknown_symbol, FLAGS_vocab, argv + 1,
include/fst/fst.h:                if (FLAGS_v >= 2) {
include/fst/log.h:                #define VLOG(level) if ((level) <= FLAGS_v) LOG(INFO)
bin/fstsymbols-main.cc:           if (FLAGS_verify && !s::Verify(*fst)) return 1;
bin/fstdraw-main.cc:              FLAGS_vertical, FLAGS_ranksep, FLAGS_nodesep, FLAGS_fontsize,
```

I don't see `FLAGS_v` being defined anywhere? And yet I'm getting an error saying that somewhere in this code `FLAGS_v` is being defined. What am I missing here?

Comment: It is probably defined in a preprocessor macro. Try searching for `FLAGS_.+`

Comment: The flag is from glog http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/glog.html

Comment: @ElvissStrazdins Thanks the macro seems to be here: http://www.openfst.org/doxygen/fst/html/flags_8h_source.html now just need to figure out where the call is made...